# HP Wifi & Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, bluetooth, realtek

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 in my new HP laptop and completed the installation without any problems.

But the wifi and bluetooth is not working and not showing any wifi points around me.

I checked **ifconfig**

[image]

I checked **iwconfig**

[image]

Please anyone support me to how to solve this issue ?

```
root@jishad-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:/var/www/html/welfies# lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
DeviceName: WLAN
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
Kernel modules: wl
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [Formatting Help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: updated question, Please check.

Comment: That device is not currently supported in Linux, the kernel developer is waiting for source code from Realtek